# what is the difference this two type of function declaration?

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm reading a book on data structure in C.

I saw code like this in exercise,

This is structure declaration.

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;
```

The Function declaration, which will head of the tree..

```
node * create (int n);  // please explain this
```

create is a function

But can we write this?

```
int create (int n);
```

Which one to use and what is the advantage of former declaration of function?

Comment: `int create (int n);` dosen't have any connection with the structure and returns `int`  whereas `node * create (int n);` returns a pointer to the structure and has some connection with the structure. Since both are different,the one you can use depends upon your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- C allows to return a pointer from a function!

To do so, you can declare like this..

```
int * myFunction(int N)
{. . .}
```

Means it will take integer `N` as parameter and return a pointer of Type `int`.

**Note :**

> Point to remember is that, it is not good idea to return the address
>   of a local variable to outside of the function so you would have to
>   define the local variable as static variable.

Like,

```
 int * myFunction(int N) {
 static int M[10]
 ....
 return M;
 }
```

Coming to your question...

```
node * create (int n);
```

Means function create will take integer parameter `n` and it will return a pointer to `node`.

So use,

- `node * create (int n);` to return a pointer
  And
- `int create (int n);`  to return a integer!!

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Well explained!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`node * create (int n);`

Function is `create` which will accept one `int` argument [`n`] and will return a pointer to `node`.

`int create (int n);`

Function is `create` which will accept one `int` argument [`n`] and will return an `int`.

In your case, `node` is a typedef to a structure, clearly not an `int`. So, you cannot *replace* the first function prototype with the later one. They both have dirrerent return type. So, the comparison for `advantage` is pointless.

`Which one to use` -- depends on your need.

1. If you want your function to return a pointer [*possibly a pointer to the the newly allocated node, (in success case, or `NULL` in failure case)*], you need to use `node * create (int n);` You can later use the pointer to newly allocated node in the caller function.
2. If you want your function to return **only** a success or failure indication [maybe 1 and 0], then you can use `int create (int n);`

Comment: I would add, when returning a pointer, using "NULL" as failure value can cover both use cases.

Comment: @Antonio Thanks. Updating answer to add your view.

Answer (score 0):

```
node * create (int n);
```

This function takes `n` as argument and returns a pointer of type `node *`. Here `node` is a structure which is defined as above and this function returns a pointer to this structure.
You should not use `int` as return type for this function since it is returning a pointer, not a value.

Comment: Thanks for answering, as I don't have 15 reputations, so can not upvote thank you!!